# Trying to add Stripe Elements to my create-react-app and I'm getting the React "Invalid hook call..." error on whatever page I add it to

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, stripe-payments

I am quite new to Stripe and fairly new to React, so I need help troubleshooting - hopefully I am just forgetting something simple. I am building an app on create-react-app with modular Firebase, cloud functions, react-router-dom v6 and hopefully Stripe Elements. The error gives 3 reasons I could be getting it (React's page on that: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) - I don't think I'm breaking the rules of hooks, since everything works fine as long as I don't try to add Elements to any component, and I only see one version of React and react-dom in my app when I run `npm ls react` and `npm ls react-dom`. Maybe I have more than one copy of React - can Stripe Elements be adding another copy? I've tried adding react and react-dom as peer dependencies, but I can't complete the final step of editing webpack because I don't have access to it with create-react-app. On the Stripe discord page, they told me they didn't know enough about React to troubleshoot, so I'm hoping that someone here will recognize what I'm doing wrong. Here is an example of my PaymentForm component:

```
import { getApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getAuth, EmailAuthProvider, linkWithCredential} from 'firebase/auth'
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

import CardPaymentForm from "../CardPaymentForm"
const stripePromise = loadStripe(my public key here);

export const PaymentFormPage = () => {
 return (
  <div className="paymentFormPage flex-col">
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        {/* CardPaymentForm would go here */}
    </Elements>
  </div>
 )


}
```

Has anyone had any experience with troubleshooting this? Any obvious things I might have done wrong, or places to start first?

Comment: Should you be importing from `'@stripe/stripe-js';` and `'@stripe/react-stripe-js'` instead of `'<@stripe>/stripe-js'` and `'<@stripe>/react-stripe-js'`?

Comment: That's how they do it in the docs - what are the angle braces for?

Comment: What docs are you looking at? The docs I found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider) look like normal imports. I don't think the "<>" should be there.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, my mistake - I looked at my code and not the code here - see above.